# If connection fails between linked servers on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, linked-server

I have 2 databases on 2 different SQL Server instances which are not in the same local network area.

What I need is when I have changes on table A in database A, I want to update table B in database B.

So I decided to link those servers but my question is if connection between servers is lost and I get update/insert/delete on database A, how can I apply those changes on database B later when connection is available again? Do I get any automatic generated log for that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A possible answer is a TableB on server A and then use Synch Framework to synch TableB to server B.  But I like the answer from voo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your update in two parts (1-st - for the first server, 2-nd - for the linked one) and execute each part in single transaction. If the second transaction fails, insert your update parameters into some table of failed updates. Schedule this table for each hour (or daily) to try to execure UPDATE, and onsucceed remove the update record from table of failed updates.

**UPDATED**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    --UPDATE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --INSERT INTO UpdateFail TABLE
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END CATCH
```

Comment: thanks for your help voo. So idea is basically, if go into the details a bit; I should put try catch around 2nd transaction and if I get any exception, I should catch those into a temp-failed transactions table. Then I can use a Sql job with a sp to schedule failed updates into table B. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @batmaci Yes, correct. Create a try-catch block (see updated answer), and schedule UpdateFail table

Answer (score 0):

this is called offline application...recently i have done application like this which is running offline if there is no connection to anohter database means it will save on local database and later on when connection is back i am using openrowset to transfer data on other side as tables structure is same on both side

and i am checking that row is exist on otherside then & then i insert otherwise i will just update
i have created store procedure for that in which i am paasing connection parameters